# How to merge multi reducers to same level state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to get follow structure state.

```
{
     product: {
         items: [],
         fetching: true,
         selected: []
     }
}
```

items & fetching is handled by HttpReducer, selected is handled by ProductSelectReducer, how to merge multi reducers's state to same level?

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever keys you pass to the `combineReducers` function gets translated into the app state. Furthermore, you can use `combineReducers` as many times as you want to created nested structures.

You should think your app state structure in such a way that it maps to simple reducers.

Comment: what is your current structure?? what is the problem with the current structure?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reducers/product.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const items = HttpReducer(...)
const fetching = HttpReducer(...)
const selected = ProductSelectReducer(...)

export default combineReducers(
  items,
  fetching,
  selected,
)
```

reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import productReducer from './products'

export default combineReducers(
  product: productReducer,
)
```

This reducer structure would result in the structure you're looking for.